# simple join syntax not properly working

Tags: oracle, hibernate, oracle11g, jpql

I'd like to show the number of records in the history table grouped by name of service

- service(code,name)
- history(id, code,....)

Please note that there is no relationship between the two table history and service, history stores the activity independently from the other tables

I have tested this sql query and it returns the expected result:

```
select s.name, count(*) from history c
join service s
on c.code=s.code 
where c.state='INITIALE'
group by s.name
```

Actually, I'd like to write it in jpql, I did alike

```
 Query query =entityManager.createQuery(" select s.name, count(*) from  ServiceEntity s join"
                + " HistoryEntity c  "
                + " where c.code=s.code and c.state='INITIALE'"
                + " group by c.name order by c.name"
                );
```

I got this **error** : *Path expected for join!....
                   Invalid path: 'c.code'....right-hand operand of a binary operator was null....unexpected end of subtree*

Comment: The two queries use different tables. The first query uses the `service` and `history` tables while the second uses the `ServiceEntity` and `HistoryEntity` tables. What happens when you test the second query in a query tool such as SQL*Plus or SQL Developer? Does it execute properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("select s.name, count(s) from  ServiceEntity s, HistoryEntity c "
                + " where c.code = s.code and c.state = 'INITIALE'"
                + " group by s.name order by s.name"
                );
```